# Como lidar com vetores em um banco de dados MySQL?

Tags: mysql, array

Tenho uma aplicação que de caixa de supermercado em que após o final da venda precisa inserir um registro com dados referentes à essa venda em uma tabela, neste registro deve estar incluso o código dos produtos comprados e a quantidade de cada um.

Como estou utilizando um banco de dados MySQL não existem vetores (arrays), como deveria proceder em uma situação como essa? Existe uma boa prática que possa ser aplicada ao esse caso?

Eu tinha pensado em fazer o seguinte, mas acho que isso é uma gambiarra:

```
codigo    vendedor    cod_produtos    quant_produtos    data
     1           3     "1,5,3,6,9"     "5,10,7,13,2"    12/12/2013
```

No caso os campos cod_produtos e quant_produtos são do tipo char/varchar/nvarchar e caso precisa-se obter os dados para gerar um relatório ou algo tipo utilizaria algo como `string[] codigos = codProdutos.Split(',');` (em C#), para obter os dados em forma de vetor.

Comment: Você pode modificar seu banco de dados?!

Comment: @FelipeOriani sim, qualquer coisa.

Comment: Boa prática é seguir as formas normais
http://www.luis.blog.br/primeira-forma-normal-1fn-normalizacao-de-dados.aspx

Comment: Existe algo chamado "Normalização". Dá uma olhada em: http://www.macoratti.net/cbmd1.htm

Comment: Vlw pela dica e @Ecil.

Comment: O que você gostaria de fazer é possível nos bancos NoSQL. Neles você consegue armazenar coleções em um campo. Bancos de dados relacionais requerem técnicas de modelagem mais aprimoradas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você tem que criar uma tabela associativa, é o jeito mais correto de se fazer, exemplo:

tbl_venda_assoc_produto

```
fk_venda  fk_produto quantidade
 1           1           5
 1           2           1
```

e na sua tabela de venda você mantém o código, vendedor e data.

Por que fazer desta forma? 1 pedido pode ter vários produtos e um produto pode estar em vários pedidos, ou seja, uma associação n pra n, requer uma tabela associativa...

Answer (score 5):

Quando passei por situações semelhentes fiz algo do tipo:

```
codigo    vendedor produto  quantidade data
 1           3     1        5          12/12/2013
 1           3     5        10         12/12/2013
 1           3     3        7          12/12/2013
 1           3     6        13         12/12/2013
 1           3     9        2          12/12/2013
```

Sendo que produto faz parte da chave da tabela. Imagina uma query querendo saber quanto foi vendido de um produto no total usando o exemplo que você sugeriu e a minha sugestão.

Answer (score 1):

O ideal seria adicionar uma tabela para associar a relação entre Venda e Produto, e nesta aplicar a quantidade, exemplo:

```
FK_VENDA   FK_PRODUTO    QUANTIDADE
1          1             5
1          5             10
1          3             7
1          4             13
1          9             2
```

Considerando que você possui a tabela `VENDA` e `PRODUTO`, o script seria algo assim:

```sql
CREATE TABLE VendaItem
(
FK_VENDA int,
FK_PRODUTO int,
QUANTIDADE int,
FOREIGN KEY (FK_VENDA) REFERENCES VENDA(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (FK_PRODUTO) REFERENCES PRODUTO(ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Em termos de SQL o correto seria separar as tabelas de acordo com as *entidades* envolvidas:

- Venda: codigo (PK), vendedor, data
- Produto_Venda: codigo_venda (PK, FK), cod_produto (PK, FK), quantidade, valor_unitario

Nesse caso, a tabela Produto_Venda tem um relacionamento N:1 (N para 1) com a tabela Venda. Isso significa que, cada Venda pode ter vários Produto_Venda.